# How to generically update an existing environment variable to .env file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, environment-variables, dotenv

I am using dotenv to load env variables and use in my mocha test. But based on a function that is generating a new token value for one of the existing environment var, I want to be able to generically update its value to .env file. Is it possible?

testSpec.js :

```
require('dotenv').config()
const webapi = require('../libs/webapi')

async function getVal() {
//to generate a new token using existing one
token = webapi.generate( process.env.BASE_URI, process.env.C_KEY, process.env.AUTH_TOKEN)
token.then(response => {
        obj = JSON.parse(response.body)
        authToken = obj.auth_token
})
}
```

.env :

```
BASE_URI= https://www.smthing.com
C_KEY=12456704-fedrfg1-7840-00002345
AUTH_TOKEN=75638391-9c5c-d690-4fd53456
```

From testSpec.js generate() generates a new token value that I'm parsing i.e; authToken ; that I want to generically update in the .env file for AUTH_TOKEN var in place of its previous value. Is it possible to write/update to .env for its updated value through some lib? I am new to nodejs and using npm packages, any help appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you want to update process.env items and then just write that to your .env file. Not sure if it's good practice, though, since I think the .env file is usually thought of as being "set once and consume"

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that can perhaps address what you're trying to do:

```js
    const fs = require('fs');
    const envItems = ['BASE_URI', 'C_KEY', 'AUTH_TOKEN'];
    function updateEnv(items = [], eol = '\n'){
      const envContents = items
        .map(item => `${item}=${process.env[item]}`)
        .join(eol)
      fs.writeFileSync('.env', envContents);
    }
```

In the part where you set your auth_token, you'd update the environment variable and `.env` file:

```
process.env.AUTH_TOKEN = obj.auth_token;
updateEnv(envItems);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is good but it requires manually adding all existing keys in .env otherwise they will be removed in the updated file. Here's my version:

updateEnv.js

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const fs = require('fs')
const env = fs.readFileSync('.env')
const buf = Buffer.from(env)
const currentConfig = dotenv.parse(buf)

function updateEnv(config = {}, eol = '\n'){
  const envContents = Object.entries({...currentConfig, ...config})
    .map(([key,val]) => `${key}=${val}`)
    .join(eol)
  fs.writeFileSync('.env', envContents);
}

module.exports = updateEnv
```

callingFile.js

```
  const updateEnv = require('./updateEnv.js')

  const envUpdate = {
    'API_KEY': 'abcdefg'
  }

  updateEnv(envUpdate)
```